# Scipy test issue - pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: python, scipy, osx-mountain-lion, nose

I installed Numpy and Scipy on Mac os X (mountain lion) by compiling from the source.

The numpy test result is great. But there is an issue with scipy test.

```
In [1]: import scipy

In [2]: scipy.test()
Running unit tests for scipy
NumPy version 1.6.2
NumPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
SciPy version 0.11.0
SciPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy
Python version 2.7.3 (default, Dec  4 2012, 00:30:38) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))]
nose version 1.2.1
.....................................................................................................................................................................................   
F.FFPython(66098,0x7fff74ae5180) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe9cb2e07b0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Any one knows how to solve this problem?

It seems to be a bug thank to pv.

```
test_definition (test_basic.TestDoubleIFFT) ... FAIL
test_definition_real (test_basic.TestDoubleIFFT) ... ok
test_djbfft (test_basic.TestDoubleIFFT) ... FAIL
test_random_complex (test_basic.TestDoubleIFFT) ... FAIL
Python(66990,0x7fff74ae5180) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9f53d8dec0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I am curious about the rest of the tests. It would be fine if this failed test is the only issue.

How can I skip this failed test and continue with the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Run with `scipy.test("full", verbose=2)`, storing the output to a file, and file a bug report:
http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/  (but try searching first if the issue is known)

Comment: I am curious about the rest of the tests It would be fine if this failed test is the only issue. 

How can I skip this failed test and continue with the rest?

Comment: See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/TESTS.rst.txt  Most of the test files are also runnable by themselves and via the nosetests command --- https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/